# How can I debug this webclient exception?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.android, webclient

I am trying to pull a simple RSS feed for an Android App with this code:

```
public async Task<IList<Episode>> PullEpisodesAsync(int page)
    {
        string xmlFeed = "";

        try
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var uri = new Uri(Const.FeedEndpoint);  // http://spotlightenglish.com/feeds/appfeed/
                xmlFeed = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, "GET", "");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException wex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebExceptionStatus: {0}", wex.StackTrace);
        }

        IList<Episode> episodes = ParseFeed(xmlFeed);

        return episodes;
    }
```

I get a runtime exception that doesn't give me much to go on:

> WebExceptionStatus:   at
>   System.Net.WebClient+c_*async15.MoveNext ()
>
>   [0x00000] in :0     --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.String].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>
>   Spotlight.EpisodePoller+c*_async1.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000e2] in
>   /Users/Jannie/Workshop/SpotlightEnglish/Elements/EpisodePoller.cs:52
>   [spotlight] Web exception: An error occurred performing a WebClient
>   request.

I am not behind a proxy or a firewall, can browse the feed url via the test device and have Internet access specified in my app manifest.

Any pointers on how to start debugging this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `ex.Message`? Have you tried [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294.aspx)?

Comment: ex.Message: `An error occurred performing a WebClient request.`

Comment: Yay!! `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code with `HttpClient` works for me:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = "http://spotlightenglish.com/feeds/appfeed/";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
    var msg = await client.GetAsync(url);
    if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var xml = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // do whatever with xml from here
    }
}
```

Also your code seems to be a bit wrong. Why are you **Uploading** something to the server rather than **Downloading**?

Comment: Good approach, thanks! I was trying different webclient methods that allowed me to manage arguments easily, but I will just append them to the uri string.